# Have window cut off floated div instead of pushing it over

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, position

Currently I have a section on a website that has some absolute text that overlays an image. This looks good when the window is large, but i want to use a media query at a certain point in the window.

Anyways, here's what is currently happening:
http://gyazo.com/ae86c3b3ab4028f32ad6ad6c846fb151

The floated right image is moving as i make the window the smaller. I want it to stay in place and just have the window cut it off. Keep in mind I **DO NOT** want a horizontal scrollbar to appear when it cuts it off, i just want the section cut off to be gone.

HTML

```
<div class="sectionone">
        <div class="headingwrap">
            <h2>Heading Text</h2>
            <h3>Subheading Text</h3>
            <a href="">Free Demo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgwrap">
            <img src="resources/chloestore.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.imgwrap {
    width:70%;
    min-width:700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    margin-top:74px;
    margin-bottom:1000px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;

}
.headingwrap {
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:50px;
    float:left;
    color: #464646;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: You can try giving a `postion:fixed` for your `img`, along with a `left` (and  top?) parameter as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:fixed; right:0;` on your image as that makes the image not move when the window is resized.

```html
<div class="sectionone">
        <div class="headingwrap">
            <h2>Heading Text</h2>
            <h3>Subheading Text</h3>
            <a href="">Free Demo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgwrap">
            <img src="resources/chloestore.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.imgwrap {
    width:70%;
    min-width:700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    margin-top:74px;
    margin-bottom:1000px;
    position:fixed; /* This is the important part */
    right:0px; /* May not need this */
}

img {
    width: 100%;

}
.headingwrap {
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:50px;
    float:left;
    color: #464646;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm pretty sure position fixed is supposed to make it move with the window. At least vertically because that's how I have my header set up to move with the page scroll.

Comment: This should work, position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; for your image

Comment: Have you tried removing your float then using my code given?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it seems to give the same affect, only this time the image is going in front of my text. It's still moving with the window though.

Comment: You can explore the other methods on this page, I have not tested them and do not know J-Query but  maybe one of them might work. https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you may want to loose the float and use position instead. Something like this:

It's a bit easier to see in
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx8ocubs/), try resizing the result frame.

```css
body{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-width:600px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a6c643609e2ddf36223bdf5d61f0866?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
```